# protools shortcuts template for nuendo

Tags: pro-tools, nuendo

hi, just new here
looking for this template so I dont forget PTs shortcuts, will be usefull when I do freelance work in PT studios

there are posts in forums directing to such a file on a site called nuendo.post, but the site is down

does anybody have this file?

Answer (score 3):

Just learn both. 
Ain't that hard anyway. When I was new to Nuendo I tried to mimic the behavior of PT in Nuendo. Was waste of time. Didn't fully learn to use Nuendo as its full potential.

After trashing my self made PT key commands set I really learned Nuendo.
And I still remember every key command I need in PT also even tho I don't use it that much nowadays.

Just write down the most important PT key commands to you and you'll soon remember the rest when sitting again in front of PT.
Bye / Tumppi

Comment: Heck, I still remember a bunch of quick-key commands for Sonic Solutions, and I haven't used it in 12 years!

Comment: Sonis Solutions! Those where the days :-)

Comment: Agreed! Nuendo is not Pro Tools and Vice Versa! Emulating same behavior is way to hell.

Answer (score 1):

As its not really possible to work in exactly the same way in PT and Nuendo, it really isn't that helpful.
We actually started out trying to. But our layout has since evolved into its own system. Some parts are still loosely based on the PT keyset like zoom, top/tail, crossfade and the simple drop marker. It makes it easier for first timers.

Otoh I never found the cubendo default layout to be very helpful in post. 
The more intuitive and logical you can make the reasoning behind how you set the keyboard up the easier it will be to remember.
Make sure all your favourite editing and mixing commands are easily accessible. Read through ALL the available key commands from time to time. You WILL find new clever ways to deal with complex situations easier and faster. Don't overlook the power of macros and the project logical editor. It can do magic stuff :).

Answer (score 1):

I do believe in the keybindings section of nuendo there is a "protools" preset, but I have found that they do not really transfer well and you just end up lost trying to use pro tools key bindings in nuendo.